# can't find method using null

Tags: dart, flutter

Some method is initializing with null. There is no warnings or errors anywhere. And I triple checked the code that I thought had a mistake but I could not find anything.

Console Log Snippet:

I/flutter (21233): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21233): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:

I/flutter (21233): The method '[]' was called on null.

I/flutter (21233): Receiver: null

I/flutter (21233): Tried calling:

I/flutter (21233): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

I/flutter (21233): #0
Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)

I/flutter (21233): #1
ButtonsLists.foodList (package:customer/lists.dart:35:71)

I/flutter (21233): #2
ButtonsLists.foodList (package:customer/lists.dart:33:24)

=========================================================================

https://gist.github.com/Norman518/17be934d342b7523e80c7abc2e40aced

```dart
 final List<MainButtons> buttonList = [
    MainButtons(Icons.domain, 'Class Supplies', Page(suppliesList)),
    MainButtons(Icons.local_dining, 'Food and Snacks', Page(foodList)),
    MainButtons(Icons.hot_tub, 'Personal Supplies', Page(toiletriesList)),
    MainButtons(Icons.local_cafe, 'Drinks', Page(drinksList))
  ];
```

```
  MainButtons(this.image, this.name, this.onTap);

  final IconData image;
  final String name;
  final Route onTap;
  .
  .
  .
   onTap: () {
         Navigator.of(context).push(onTap);
       },
```

=========================================================================

I expect four inkwell buttons to be displayed.

=========================================================================

Did the change, here is the console output

I/flutter ( 4037): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4037): The following CyclicInitializationError was thrown building Builder:

I/flutter ( 4037): Reading static variable 'suppliesList' during its initialization

I/flutter ( 4037): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

I/flutter ( 4037): #0      ButtonsLists.suppliesList (package:customer/lists.dart:26:24)

I/flutter ( 4037): #1      new ButtonsLists (package:customer/lists.dart:55:54)

I/flutter ( 4037): #2      new BuyItem (package:customer/buyItem.dart:66:35)

I/flutter ( 4037): #3      ButtonsLists.buyItemList (package:customer/lists.dart:8:5)

I/flutter ( 4037): #4      ButtonsLists.buyItemList (package:customer/lists.dart:7:23)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here

```
BrowsePage(this.buttonList);
final List<Widget> buttonList;
```

instead try this way

```
 final List<Widget> buttonList;
 BrowsePage(this.buttonList);
```

Comment: i switched them, got a new error, i added the error in my post

Comment: they are in the right order, i got the buttons to work with a different solution but with that solution i couldnt navigate to the other screens

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the list in the login page and buyitem, put it in the browsepage.